# Chrome screen Print is messed up?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I need to print a report from my MVC application. Below is what I get when print in chrome. The content is moved to the right of the screen.It was working in Chrome. But its showing like this in Chrome now and all other browsers are ok.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary anx-control" onclick="print()">
    <i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;@LCL.Common_Labels.PrintPage
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to provide an answer.  We'd need to see the relevant HTML and CSS... the minimum code required to produce the error.  Also, we'd need to know your Chrome version that exhibits the problem.  This could just be a bug in Chrome.